# Add img with a variable src in django

Tags: python, html, django

This is a sample template code in which i should be receiving the url to profile picture from views.py , when i try to print the received path it is correct however the image is not visible,
i tried adding {{STATIC_URL}} and creating a /static/ folder where the settings.py exist however this changed nothing still cant view an image ,
here is the template code

```
{% block content %}
<img src="{{profilepicture}}" height="200" width="200"/>

<H2>{{name}}</H2>
</br>
<H2>{{username}}</H2>
</br>
<H2> {{date}} </H2>
</br>
<H2> {{residence}} </H2>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit:
i tried using {{STATIC_URL}}{{profilepicture}} with no success ( i moved the photos into static folder)

Comment: what does the  `img` tag of the rendered html look like ? Also, i believe itis `profilepicture.url`

Comment: Please show us where is located the profile picture and the view that renders this template

Comment: [link](photos/a.png)